# Show plugin incompatibility error on plugin page in wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I am developing a custom plugin for woocommerce. For now i support it for few version of woocommerce. So i want to check and show incompatibility error if some is using lower version of woocommerce than the version i minimal support.

I want to show the error message on plugin page in admin panel under the my plugin listed.
I have function to get woocommerce version and checking incompatibility using if else condition. But i have no idea how to display the error message as i want.

So please help.

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is how I do it in my own plugin:

```
add_action( 'plugins_loaded', 'so_31217783_version_test' );
function so_31217783_version_test(){
    $required_woo = '2.1.0';
    if ( ! defined( 'WC_VERSION' ) || version_compare( WC_VERSION, $required_woo, '<' ) ) {
        add_action( 'admin_notices', 'so_31217783_admin_notice' );
        return false;
    }

    // add the rest of your actions here
    // they will only be triggered if the 
    // version test has been passed
}


function so_31217783_admin_notice() {
    echo '<div class="error"><p>' . sprintf( __( 'My custom plugins requires at least WooCommerce version %s in order to function. Please upgrade WooCommerce.', 'your-custom-function' ), $required_woo ) . '</p></div>';
}
```

The base explanation is that you check the version of WooCommerce very early on and then shut down your plugin if the minimum version is not met. You also add a function to the `admin_notices` hook so that you can tell the user what has happened.

Comment: Not sure if it will have any effect, but in the case of false positives (maybe your plugin loads before WC) you might try changing the `plugins_loaded` to `woocommerce_init`.